# Make only numeric entries blank

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with UK postcodes in it. Unfortunately some of the postcode data is incorrect - ie, they are only numeric (all UK postcodes should start with a alphabet character)

I have done some research and found the grepl command that I've used to generate a TRUE/FALSE vector if the entry is only numeric,

```
Data$NewPostCode <- grepl("^.*[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+.*$|.*[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+.*$",Data$PostCode)
```

however, what I really want to do is where the instance starts with a number to make the postcode blank.

Note, I don't want remove the rows with an incorrect postcode as I will lose information from the other variables. I simply want to remove that postcode

Example data

```
Area               Postcode
Birmingham         B1 1AA
Manchester         M1 2BB
Bristol            BS1 1LM
Southampton        1254
London             1290C
Newcastle          N1 3DC
```

Desired output

```
Area               Postcode
Birmingham         B1 1AA
Manchester         M1 2BB
Bristol            BS1 1LM
Southampton        
London             
Newcastle          N1 3DC
```

Comment: `1290C` also have `letter` C.  If it is a type, `df1$Postcode[!is.na(as.numeric(df1$Postcode))] <- ""`

Comment: The regex "^[0-9]" should match everything that starts with a number. So something like `ifelse(grepl("^[0-9]", Data$PostCode), "", Data$PostCode)` ?

Comment: Yes - that works.  Ideally I'd like a further step that tests the data for the genuine structure of a UK postcode (eg, AA## or A# or A##) and make blank if it doesn't fit these but this solution gets rid of the majority of incorrect entries

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to go between TRUE/FALSE vectors and the kind of task you want, but I prefer `ifelse`. A simpler way to generate the type of logical vector you're looking for is

```
grepl("^[0-9]", Data$PostCode)
```

which will be TRUE whenever PostCode starts with a number, and FALSE otherwise. You may need to adjust the regex if your needs are more complex.

You can then define a new column which is blank whenever the vector is TRUE and the old value whenever the vector is FALSE, as follows:

```
Data$NewPostCode <- ifelse(grepl("^[0-9]", Data$PostCode), "", Data$PostCode)
```

(May I suggest using NA instead of blank?)